# What's the recommended way of running a stand-alone clojure REPL?

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I'm using rlwrap, but I don't have tab-completion, and characters with accents get mangled. This is on OSX 10.6 in Terminal.app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-f` flag to rlwrap to enable tab completion.  It's going to be static completion though, based on a static list of symbols in some file you specify.  If you want dynamic completion (based on any symbol that's currently defined in your running REPL), you should try Emacs + SLIME or equivalent.

In any case, here's one way to generate a list of symbols to tab-complete.  You will have to regenerate this file from time to time because new symbols are added to Clojure's core in every version.  (This code works with bleeding edge clojure-contrib; `clojure.contrib.io` was called `duck-streams` in earlier versions.)

```
user> (use 'clojure.contrib.io)
nil
user> (with-out-writer "/home/user/.clj-tabcompletion"
        (doseq [[sym _] (ns-publics 'clojure.core)]
          (println sym)))
nil
```

Then:

```
$ rlwrap -f ~/.clj-tabcompletion java -jar clojure.jar
Clojure 1.2.0-master-SNAPSHOT
user=> def<TAB>
definline    defmacro     defmethod    defmulti     defn         defonce      defprotocol  defstruct    deftype
user=> def
```

If your terminal is mangling characters with accents, you likely have an encoding or locale problem.  It works fine for me.  I don't use OS X and don't know what terminal you use, so I can't help.  In Konsole in Linux, inside rlwrap:

```
user=> (println "àèìòùáéíóúäëïöüâêîôûãõñ")
àèìòùáéíóúäëïöüâêîôûãõñ
nil
user=> (println "牛が牧場で草を食べている。")
牛が牧場で草を食べている。
nil
```

Answer (score 3):

[ClojureX](http://github.com/citizen428/ClojureX) attempts to be just what you want to OS X users. I've got no experience with it myself (I'm a Linux user), but I'm under the impression that the ClojureX folks will be willing to help you if you run into weird problems (character mangling? I don't get that, with or without rlwrap...).

Update: Here's a link to [an announcement on the Clojure group](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/d3896413a73a06bd/419ad3d8a8b062fe?lnk=gst) re: some recent changes in ClojureX...

There's a second option for readline-like functionality in JVM-based console apps -- [jline](http://jline.sourceforge.net/). Use something like

```
java -cp $CLASSPATH jline.ConsoleRunner clojure.main
```

(with jline.jar included in `$CLASSPATH`, of course) if you'd like to give it a try.

<strike>Also, I don't think I've ever heard of tab completion in stand-alone Clojure REPLs. Most people use Emacs / Aquamacs + SLIME, Vimclojure or some Java IDE with a Clojure plugin for stuff like that.</strike> Well, some other people have heard about it alright (see Brian's answer). And I've since found [this description](http://wrost.blogspot.com/2009/08/clojure-tab-completion-on-windows.html) of how to set up tab completion with jline. *And* I've since checked the sources for ClojureX -- it does set up tab completion for you. That makes this part of my original answer a bit of a blunder, I guess... But the fact remains that ClojureX is a very safe bet which may save you the trouble of configuring things yourself.